# Gov2: list of who is voting on what | Polkadot.js api

Tags: polkadot-js, api, gov2

I'm building an automation for the Gov2 referenda module, testing right now using wss://governance2-testnet.litentry.io test network with polkadot.js app

Differently from what the democracy module we currently have in Polkadot and Kusama, I cannot retrieve anymore **the list of who is currently voting on what**. Not even from the [api calls](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#referenda). Am I missing something ? or is the new system supposed to not store that information anymore?

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: can you please be more specific about what queries and code you are using, and what expected output you want?

Answer (score 2):

With PolkadotJS you can get information about a specific referendum with this code:

```
const referenda = await api.query.referenda.referendumInfoFor(48);
console.log(`Referenda: ${JSON.stringify(referenda.toHuman())}`);
```

And you get the total number of ayes and nayes votes, with other information:

```json
    Referenda: {"Ongoing":{"track":"0","origin":{"system":"Root"},"proposal":{"Lookup":{"hash_":"0x4bdd1d956c24c6dc9ce1c07f6c3cc1a82d5db63dc6d895bdd5a035f60ef58006","len":"106"}},"enactment":{"After":"100"},"submitted":"16,019,459","submissionDeposit":{"who":"DrQ3WAwSyMsZpaUvwP11j63QJC2wmGUH3BWPoxj5kqgA3A1","amount":"33,333,333,333"},"decisionDeposit":null,"deciding":null,"tally":{"ayes":"24,025,722,234,946,176","nays":"72,721,623,600,000,000","support":"17,151,464,474,841,370"},"inQueue":false,"alarm":["16,221,059",["16,221,059","0"]]}}
```

[Is this one in Kusama](https://kusama.polkassembly.io/referenda/48)

Also you can get the list of all referendums (Finished and OnGoing):

```
const allEntries = await api.query.democracy.referendumInfoOf.entries();
    allEntries.forEach(([{ args: [id] }, referendum]) => {
        console.log(`${id}: Referendum: ${JSON.stringify(referendum.toHuman())}`);
 });
```

But if you want to see who vote in that referendum I suggest you to use the SUBSCAN API, the endpoint [/scan/democracy/votes](https://support.subscan.io/#democracy-votes) where you can get the voters specifying the referendum ID.

This is what Polkassembly is using to get all the voters. Check their [code here](https://support.subscan.io/#democracy-votes).

```js
     fetch(`https://kusama.api.subscan.io/api/scan/democracy/votes`,
            {
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    page: currentPage,
                    referendum_index: referendumId,
                    row: 10
                }),
                headers: subscanApiHeaders,
                method: 'POST'
            }).then(async (res) => {
            const votersData = await res.json();

            if(votersData && votersData.data && votersData.data.list) {
                if(!count) {
                    setCount(votersData.data.count);
                }
                setVotersList(votersData.data.list);
            }

            setLoadingStatus({
                isLoading: false,
                message: 'Loading Data'
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error('Error in fetching vote data:', err);
        });
```

Comment: this is for gov 1.0 isn't it?

Comment: In the Polkadot network is still gov 1.0 yes, but in Kusama gov 2.0 is deployed already

Comment: But when I do `await api.query.democracy.referendumInfoOf.entries()` as recommended, I only see the list of gov 1.0 referenda.

Comment: It should get you for Gov2 too, check https://kusama.polkassembly.io/ where you can switch from Gov1 to Gov2. After run await api.query.democracy.referendumInfoOf.entries() you can see in the list the gov2 too